# fragment back activity dont work

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26687485/app-exits-on-presing-back-button-inside-fragments-within-navigation-drawer) all solution on stackoverflow but none help me.

When I back from Default fragment I want to show fragment 0 but here application is close

Below is `MainActivity` code

```
   private void selectItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().addToBackStack(PageSlidingTabStripFragment.TAG)
                .replace(R.id.content,
                        PageSlidingTabStripFragment.newInstance(),
                        PageSlidingTabStripFragment.TAG).commit();
        break;
    default:

        SherlockFragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
        break;
    }

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

Second Fragment back activity

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
            fm.getBackStackEntryAt(0);

        } else {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check how an activity communicates with a fragment using an interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I control the activity's up button from a contained fragment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025331/how-can-i-control-the-activitys-up-button-from-a-contained-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Bro change your conditions in onBackPressed() : Like

```
Integer backStackSize = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if(backStackSize < 2){
            //new Logout_Dialog(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);
//YOU CAN ASK USER WHETHER HE WANTS TO LOGOUT OR NOT HERE......
        }
        else if(backStackSize >= 2){

            FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry=getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1);


                fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        }//else if(backStackSize >= 2) closes here.....
        else
        {
            //Else fragment shud be removed from Backstack.... 
            super.onBackPressed();
        }//fragment shud be removed from Backstack..
```

Comment: got The method onBackPressed() is undefined for the type SherlockFragment

Comment: @Nirav Ranpara : No, do this in your BaseActivity where you are inflating the Fragment.
Fragments does not have onBackPressed(), Activities have.

Comment: @NiravRanpara : In your MainActivity. (Assuming your MainActivity extends Activity)

If some other class which extends Activity & inflates your fragment then write the code there.

Comment: done ! no action happen . display same fragment after pressing evern 10 times back

Comment: @NiravRanpara : your control must be gng in 
`if(backStackSize < 2){
            //new Logout_Dialog(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);
}`

Put some Log here & check.

P.s. Png home now, will reply you after 2 hrs.

Comment: @NiravRanpara : Is your issue fixed ?

Comment: Did you tried to put the log ? Is the control coming in if condition ? Try debugging your code & just chk the control is coming till what line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108694/discussion-between-pawan-and-nirav-ranpara).